What is the difference between these different Google domains?
What is the difference between the following domains?

google.com
accounts.google.com
myaccount.google.com

I have saved credentials with the same Gmail address for all 3, but one has a passkey, and the other two with different passwords. What do I sign in with?


google.com is Google's search engine
accounts.google.com is Google's login interface, typically accessed because you are trying to log in to a Google product/service to which you are then redirected.
myaccount.google.com is the site where you go to manage your Google  account. You'd need to be logged in to your account first.

All Google products and services for your personal account are tied to the same Gmail address and password.  If you have two passwords saved one may be outdated. If you have a passkey setup that will be presented as an option when you try to login.
